# Install lame 3.100 under Xenial Xerus 16.04LTS?

Tags: software-installation, mp3, lame

For the first time in 7 years I see that there is a new, major release for the lame mp3 encoder, with lame 3.100 coming out on October 13th 2017.

There is [an impressive list of bugfixes](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/doc/html/history.html) which I would like to have access to. How can I *safely* install this very newest version of lame  on my Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS system?

Comment: Look here for the I believe 3.9 version not so sure but have a look: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/lame/3.99.5+repack1-9build1

Comment: Your general options are: 1. Upgrade to a version of Ubuntu with lame 3.100 , 2. Wait for lame 3.100 to appear in backports (or make a request) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Requesting_New_Backports , 3. find a ppa with lame 3.100 , or 4. compile yourself - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software . Pick an option and post back if you have a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *safest* method that I have found that for the most part will not interfere with any system installation is to take a page from [the FFmpeg trac site](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and install *a local copy* of lame.

The following single command gave me a working executable of the latest lame, safely installed in `$HOME/bin`:

```
mkdir -v $HOME/{lame_build,bin} && cd $HOME/lame_build && \
sudo apt-get install nasm build-essential && \
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/lame/lame-3.100.tar.gz && \
tar xvf lame-3.100.tar.gz && cd lame-3.100 && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" \
./configure \
       --prefix="$HOME/lame_build" \
       --bindir=$HOME/bin \
       --enable-static \
       --disable-shared \
       --enable-nasm  && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install
```

The detritus can then be removed with the following command:

```
rm -rfv $HOME/lame_build
```

The following now shows on my system:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
andrew@corinth:~$ lame --version | head -n 1
LAME 64bits version 3.100 (http://lame.sf.net)
andrew@corinth:~$
```

And all is well :)